# Android: Single TextView with set Spannable.Factory or two simple TextFields with plain text? What is faster?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I am wondering what is faster? A single `TextView` with set `Spannable.Factory` (which applies two styles to text) or two simple `TextViews` with plain text?
As this is inside of a list item (so re-rendered on scroll) it may be not so unsignificant as it may seem.

Comment: Thanks guys for both comments, I mark them both +1, but they're ...exclusive ;), Thanks for your intuitive guesses. Nontheless, more answers especially with some explanation are still welcome.

Comment: In the case at this website it seems two textviews would be faster: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2013/09/17/android-performance-bits-and-pieces-part-i-measure-everything.html

Answer (score 1):

Citing [Zsolt Vasvari via Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/yMaCOlkAHTc):

> *"My guess, all else being equal, is that a View is a much "heavier" 
>   object than a Spannable.  But which one is better is impossible to say 
>   because it requires to know what you want for and how you want to use 
>   the text lines for. "*

Answer (score 1):

Mind you, this is only a guess.  My feeling is that the expense you want to avoid is object creation, and that two simple Views are better than one Spannable, provided the Views are recycled.